# REST edit multiple relationship field

Tags: nodes

I'm developing a telegram bot and I'm using a Drupal site to manage data.
From my bot php code I create some nodes like this:

```
$url = "/entity/node?_format=hal_json"; 
    foreach($obj['pratiche'] as $nid){
        $pratiche[] = ["target_id" => $nid];
    }
    $opt = [
        'headers' => self::getHead(),
        'body' => json_encode([
                'type' => 'presentazione',
                'title' => [ [ 'value' => 'User ' . $obj['telegram_id'] ] ],
                'body' => [ [ 'value' => $obj['body'] ] ],
                'field_anno_di_nascita' => [ [ 'value' => $obj['nascita'] ] ],
                'field_pratiche' => [ [ 'value' =>$pratiche ] ],
          ])
    ];

    $response = $this->client->request('POST', $url , $opt);
```

As you can see field_pratiche is a node relation field and can have multiple values inserted like an array of ["target_id" => $tid] arrays. The creation is fine.

When I try to edit this node I do something like:

```
 $url = "/node/".$nid."?_format=hal_json"; 
    $editObj = [ 'type' => 'presentazione' ];

    if(array_key_exists('nascita', $obj)){
        $editObj['field_anno_di_nascita'] = [ [ 'value' => $obj['nascita'] ] ];
    }

    if(array_key_exists('presentazione', $obj)){
        $editObj['body'] =  [ [ 'value' => $obj['presentazione'] ] ];
    }

    if(array_key_exists('pratiche', $obj)){
        foreach($obj['pratiche'] as $p){
            $pratiche[] = ["target_id" => $p];
        } 
        $editObj['field_pratiche'] = [ [ 'value' => $pratiche] ];
    }

    $opt = [
        'headers' => self::getHead(),
        'body' => json_encode($editObj)
    ];
   $response = $this->client->request('PATCH', $url , $opt);
```

Using the same structure edit of 'field_pratiche' fail. After call edit I can find the new values in the other fields but an empty one for field_pratiche.

How can I achieve this ? How can I edit this multiple node relationship field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of arrays are the column names in the database. Most simple fields like integers or numbers just have one `value` column. Entity references don't have a `value`, but a `target_id` column instead.

Your (multi-value)<sup>1</sup> `$pratiche` already is an (array of)<sup>1</sup> arrays with `target_id` as key, so the `value` key is superfluent and incorrect `[ [ 'value' => $pratiche] ]`.

Instead simply assign `$editObj['field_pratiche'] = $pratiche;` directly